# Need help in using HdrHistogram java library

Tags: java, histogram, hdr, date-histogram, hdrhistogram

I am using HdrHistogram java library but I am not getting the desired output. Can you please help me understand there is an error in the library or expected value.

In this case I am expecting the output to be 1000000, but actual output is 1000003

```
import org.HdrHistogram.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Histogram histogram = new Histogram(5);
    histogram.recordValue(1000000);
    histogram.recordValue(1000001);
    histogram.recordValue(1000002);
    histogram.recordValue(90);
    histogram.recordValue(10);

    System.err.println(histogram.getValueAtPercentile(50.0));
}
}
```

Why is this happening.
My maven settings are:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hdrhistogram</groupId>
        <artifactId>HdrHistogram</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior. With 5 decimal points of specified resolution/separation (in your example), any result that is 1000000 +/- 100 would be correct. 1000003 is well within that range, and histogram.valuesAreEquivalent(1000000, 1000003) would/should return true.
Note that you can use histogram.lowestEquivalentValue(1000000) and
histogram. highestEquivalentValue(1000000) to establish the range of equivalent values.